# Snap floating windows have encoding issues

Tags: snap

In apps installed via snap floating windows have encoding issues. Here's an example with Mailspring (also happens with Discord and Microsoft Teams):[Mailspring example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr4A1.png)

Comment: It can be a different issue but it looks like you don't have the necessary font or fonts required by the software.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an encoding issue, but an issue with the font cache of your snap application.

1. Close the Mailspring application
2. Open your file manager, and let it to show hidden files. Locate the mailspring configuration folder under the "snap" folder in your home directory.
3. Locate the ".cache/fontconfig" folder, and delete it.
4. Restart Mailspring: its fontconfig folder will be recreated based on the contents of your "~/.cache/fontconfig" folder

If it does not work, first refresh your font cache by entering following commands in the terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/fontconfig
fc-cache -r -v
```

and then repeat the steps above.